# Routing doesn't show but works behind in domain redirection

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, redirect, heroku, sails.js

I have a domain and I am redirecting it to some bitly link of Heroku with masking. But I am not able to see the routing in the url happening. But it's happening behind i.e from herokuapp.

I can see the route changes in my localhost as well as in herokuapp.com. But when I use the same with other domain for the purpose of redirection. I am not able to see the route changes happening in xyz.com. I expect xyz.com/abc -> herokuapp.com/abc. Now xyz.com -> herokuapp.com/abc, herokuapp.com/def. All the routes are happening but xyz.com is not getting changed. Because of this I am not able to bookmark the pages or send the links to other users.

Is it possible to do, if so how can we achieve this? Do we need to create multiple domain redirections for this. If so, I don't think that works for dynamic routing.

Comment: Can you show us the content of your `.htaccess` file or any related file ?

Comment: i have not created nor made any changes in .htaccess. i just added .htaccess tag to the question. It is as simple as that in my localhost, i get all routes : http://localhost:1337/home. Same with heroku: https://xyz.herokuapp.com/home. I have domain name called pqrs.com which i am redirecting to https://xyz.herokuapp.com with masking. I can see the changes of route on any menu clicks which is doing internally with heroku. But pqrs.com/*route will not get change